# Initiator follower analysis with time series data sets

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, cross-correlation

I am a newbie to this forum. I searched different white papers and codes on google but couldn't find a solution, that's when I registered on this forum.. Please share in case you guys have a idea as to how to go about this problem..

I have a data set which consists of 30 prop. traders, and their historical trades on each symbol with trade dates..I want to understand the relationships that exist among each of these traders.. For eg: I want to understand who first trades on a stock and who follows next and so on.. basically derive the initiator-follower relationships.. And predict the same for the future...

Any ideas as to how to go about? I started by taking a difference between trade dates for each ticker for any two traders and then taking a correlation of those dates/or difference in trade dates...

I do not think this is a right approach..Any suggestions?

Comment: Basically what you are trying to do is segmentation in your examples "leader"/"laggers" or risk taker/risk averse. Data analysis can only reveal only some behavioral insights, what you might want to do is consult a domain knowledge expert or do a qual/quant market research to determine attitudinal preference on "why" they did. Also it might help if you could provide a simple example for couple of customers.